# Broken quarry in Hearthfire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I'm on PC, and when I try to mine the stone quarry at the house near Falkreath it won't activate.
Anyone else experiencing problems? Is there a way to fix it? Serana can use the quarry, and Hearthfire is installed.

Comment: Do you have the Unofficial Hearthfire Patch installed?

Comment: Do you have a pickaxe?  You need a pickaxe in your inventory to mine, but NPCs do not.  You can also grab a pickaxe and swing at it manually.  Manual mining is usually faster, and if you have related perks and shouts, it goes MUCH faster.

Answer (score 2):

Download the **Unofficial Hearthfire Patch** to fix such problems in Hearthfire like this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Shaun okay I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Load an older save if possible.
2. Get a housecarl (only possible if you finished the entrance/cottage part) and you can pay her to buy resources.
3. There are rarely random quarries in the wilderness (I've only seen one though in Rorrikstead).
4. Buy another plot of land and use its quarry.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, so i just did it manually by hitting the quarry with the pickaxe equipped.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If it does, the problem the OP has is that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Joachim as far as i remember, there are two ways to use the quarries. one is the interact button, the second is manually equipping a pickax and "attacking" it

Comment: @Dragonrage Really?! I've never known. This is awkward :) My apologies, Penelope.

Answer (score -4):

Here's a few soulutions
1.You may need to update the game
2.try waiting/sleeping
3.load older save
4.it may be out
5.wild guess but maybe stay away from It for a while